# Problems with constructor of a class with template

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, containers

I'm trying to write a container class using C++ and templates. However, I'm having a compilation error I don't understand...

The variable `elems` is a private vector, declaration is:

```
private:
  vector<DataType> elems;
```

The vector is a custom vector. Its constructor is:

```
vector::vector(int init_capacity) : vect_capacity(init_capacity), vect_size(0), vect_elems(NULL){
  assert(init_capacity >= 0);

  if (init_capacity > 0){
     vect_elems = new Object[init_capacity];
 }
```

}

The constructor can be seen below:

```
template <class DataType>
bag<DataType>::bag(int init_capacity) : elems(init_capacity) {
}
```

This code returns the following error:

```
../src/vector.h: In instantiation of ‘vector<DataType>::vector(int) [with DataType = int]’:
../src/bag.h:33:60:   required from ‘bag<DataType>::bag(int) [with DataType = int]’
../src/bag_test.cpp:6:17:   required from here
```

I honestly have no idea what could be possibly happening. Will be immensely grateful to anyone that can point me in the right direction...

Comment: Was that the whole error message?

Comment: This is only a part of the error message.

Comment: That's the only error. A few warnings here and there... but not related. I'm using calling this from a main in a test program with `bag<int> b1(10)` ... then it gives this error.

Comment: You shouldn't leave warnings lying around... if only for the fact that they obfuscate the compiler's output

Comment: It seems to be using your own `vector`.  Is this on purpose, or did you mean to use `std::vector`?  Show the constructor for the `vector` class you defined in `vector.h`.

Comment: "That's the only error." — All error messages have the word "error" in them.

Comment: Isn't there something after "required from here" usually in such output?

Comment: @KevinCadieux its included (look to the left, there's a file name, line number and column offset). Of course *we* can't see it (the source, not the location info). =P

Comment: There's usually a WHOLE trail of error messages when templates are involved

Comment: @paddy Yes, I'm using my own `vector`.

Comment: @n.m.Yes you are right, this doesn't specifically says error. However, it doesn't compile...

Comment: Paste *the whole error message*. I don't care how long it is or what you think isn't important. All you have shown is the *location* information, but the actual **error** is still not in the posted messaging.

Comment: Sorry to ask silly things, but you're only showing tantalizing snippets of code, so I must ask: is the `vector` constructor public?

Comment: Props to you @paddy. 'tis a solid educated stab.

Comment: You should never allow warnings to be emitted for your code. Not until you have reached skill level 800 and educated at least three apprentices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the very stupid question. It's true that the compiler **does** complain about this, but the code actually compiles. Thanks to @WhozCraig and @n.m who insisted that this wasn't an error, I noticed that it actually was building. Thanks! For future reference, I do post the whole message:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project ADS ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/bag_test.cpp

Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/bag_test.d" -MT"src/bag_test.d" -o "src/bag_test.o" "../src/bag_test.cpp"
In file included from ../src/bag_test.cpp:2:0:
../src/bag.h:23:66: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const bag<DataType>&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
../src/bag.h:23:66: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) 
In file included from ../src/bag.h:2:0,
                 from ../src/bag_test.cpp:2:
../src/vector.h: In instantiation of ‘vector<DataType>::vector(int) [with DataType = int]’:
../src/bag.h:34:53:   required from ‘bag<DataType>::bag(int) [with DataType = int]’
../src/bag_test.cpp:6:17:   required from here
../src/vector.h:100:6: warning: ‘vector<int>::vect_capacity’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
../src/vector.h:99:6: warning:   ‘int vector<int>::vect_size’ [-Wreorder]
../src/vector.h:108:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
Finished building: ../src/bag_test.cpp

Building target: ADS
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "ADS"  ./src/bag_test.o   
Finished building target: ADS

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: Note: I never insisted there wasn't an error. I insisted you hadn't *posted* one. I was still holding out that you missed pasting it in. I honestly didn't see a warnings-only outcome to this.

Comment: Well, at least you insisted in me posting the error, so I noticed thanks to that there wasn't an error. Thanks!